# WM 5 SDK Symbol

Tags: c#, sdk, windows-mobile, motorola-emdk

We have a large number of Window Mobile Devices (Symbol MC35 & MC70). I want to write a small app that gets the device serial number and simcard serial number (not phone number). I have tryed using the Symbol SDK and I can get the Device Serial Number for the MC70s as they have a Electronic Serial Number Module. But not sure how to get the Sim Details.
If i am unable to get the Device Serial Number From the MC35s can I get the IMEI number?

The porpose behind this is so I can keep a upto date record of what sim is in what handheld as any time. I am going to write the data to a registy file where SOTI Mobile Control will link it to that handheld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa454263.aspx) for SIM management functions. I can't find anything for retrieving a SIM ID, if such a thing exists. I suppose that you can identify the SIM by the phone number. Is it possible two different SIMs to have the same phone number? To get the phone number there is the GetPhoneNumber sample in the Windows Mobile SDK.

As for identifying the phone, the correct way is to read the Device ID. Again there is the GetDeviceID sample in the SDK (Both are in Common\CPP\Win32). Copying from the sample's read me:

> GetDeviceUniqueID protects the privacy
>   of a device. Multiple applications 
>   need to use a device's unique
>   identifier to communicate with
>   servers.  To protect a device's
>   privacy, multiple servers should not
>   be able to  correlate data from the
>   same device. GetDeviceUniqueID does
>   not use any  additional information
>   other than the data that is provided
>   by the  application, so any
>   application that passes in the same
>   application  data buffer will obtain
>   the same hash. This API can be called
>   be any application regardless of the
>   trust level of the application.

If you want to retrieve the IMEI, see for example [here](http://xman892.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-to-series-retrieving-imsi-and-imei.html).

Comment: There must be a way of getting the number from the sim card e.g. phone number or the long number f the sim. I have loked into Get DevicveUniqueID and that work but not sutible for this project.

Answer (score 2):

You're after the [lineGetGeneralInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms862517.aspx) TAPI call.  You want to look at the subscriber number, which is located using the dwSubscriberNumberSize and dwSubscriberNumberOffset members of the [LINEGENERALINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms862476.aspx) structure the call returns.